# Java ArrayList Merge function

Tags: java

During the interview, I had to write a function that merges two sorted ArrayLists. I had written this, but they said that my code works ineffective. Can someone explains me why?

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>> void merge(ArrayList<T> a, ArrayList<T> b){
    int curIndexOfA = 0;
    int curIndexOfB = 0;
    boolean bHasMoreBigElements = false;
    while(curIndexOfB < b.size()){
        if(a.get(curIndexOfA).compareTo(b.get(curIndexOfB)) >= 0){
            a.add(curIndexOfA, b.get(curIndexOfB));
            curIndexOfB++;
        }
        if(++curIndexOfA >= a.size()){
            bHasMoreBigElements = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(bHasMoreBigElements){
        for(;curIndexOfB < b.size(); curIndexOfB++){
            a.add(b.get(curIndexOfB));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kayaman what about adding a `sorted` statement before collecting? `Stream.concat(a.stream(), b.stream()).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Could you elaborate the criteria for the merge? Is the order to be preserved? Is it important which one gets merged into the other? Is one of the two supposed to be empty after the merge? How about duplicate entries?

Comment: @Lino I think the interviewer wanted to see a hand written `O(n)` merge to test the general capabilities of the interviewee. The OP "failed" the efficiency part.

Comment: It's basically just guessing what the interviewer wanted to see. Without further constraints I don't see how answering this is helping anyone.

Comment: Because your question is explicitly about the ineffectiveness of your code: Consider the case `a = { 4, 5, 6 }` and `b = { 1, 2, 3 }` - your code has to perform a lot of shift operations by calling `ArrayList.add(int, T)` which makes your algorithm's complexity `O(n*m)`. The best case for merging should be `O(n+m)`.

Comment: @Kayaman as said by Ben, without further information it is mostly just guessing what OP actually wants, so I just pasted a possible solution.

Comment: I think if we are going to use this approach we must convert list to linked list first (in which we are going to append) in which we are going to insert elements.. As inserting anything in middle in ArrayList needs shifting of all elements which is time consuming..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is not answering any of the comments, which leaves us with an unclear / too broad question

Comment: @DhaRmvEErsiNgh insertion in `LinkedList` is not more performant, because it first has to traverse `index` amount of elements

Comment: @Lino so you want say searching for index and adding element in linkedlist will take more time than adding at particular index and shifting all elements in right in an Arraylist?

Comment: @DhaRmvEErsiNgh not saying that the arrayList approach is more performant, just wanted to mention that traversing may also take "a lot of time" for linked list

Comment: @Lino yes agree. It will depend  on which index we are adding element...

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be better approach, This code will not sort merged list again and also will traverse each list element only once

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>> void merge(ArrayList<T> a, ArrayList<T> b) {

    ArrayList<T> temp = new ArrayList<>(a.size() + b.size());

    int aIndex = 0;
    int bIndex = 0;

    while (true) {

        if (aIndex == a.size() && bIndex == b.size()) {
            break;
        }

        if (aIndex == a.size() && bIndex < b.size()) {
            temp.add(b.get(bIndex++));
        } else if (bIndex == b.size() && aIndex < a.size()) {
            temp.add(a.get(aIndex++));
        } else if (a.get(aIndex).compareTo(b.get(bIndex)) <= 0) {

            temp.add(a.get(aIndex++));
        } else {
            temp.add(b.get(bIndex++));
        }

    }
    // return temp if required
    // return temp;
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Sample input:

List A [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11]

List B [2, 4, 6, 8, 11, 13, 14]

Sample output:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 13, 14]

Comment: This is the first actual answer that performs a *merge* instead of a sort.

Comment: Good solution, would you mind changing the `Integer` to `T extends Comparable<T>` and use `.compareTo` like in the question?